# Как исправить ошибку в JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я наткнулся на один видеоролик, где чувак сделал на JS змейку (хауди хо), и я решил протестить, скопировал весь код, и мне Хром в консоле 2 ошибки, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null" и "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fillStyle' of undefined". Спасайте! Вот код : https://pastebin.com/index/Hvhu7Kxn

Comment: А у вас на странице есть элемент `canvas`? Если есть, `id` этого элемента соответствует `id` из кода?

Comment: Да, есть, и соответствует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то недоглядели. Скорее всего  - `id`. Всё работает

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);
  setInterval(loop, 1000/60); // 60 FPS
}

var
  canv     = document.getElementById('mc'), // canvas
  ctx     = canv.getContext('2d'), // 2d context
  gs = fkp   = false, // game started && first key pressed (initialization states)
  speed = baseSpeed  = 3, // snake movement speed
  xv = yv    = 0, // velocity (x & y)
  px      = ~~(canv.width) / 2, // player X position
  py      = ~~(canv.height) / 2, // player Y position
  pw = ph    = 20, // player size
  aw = ah    = 20, // apple size
  apples    = [], // apples list
  trail    = [], // tail elements list (aka trail)
  tail     = 100, // tail size (1 for 10)
  tailSafeZone  = 20, // self eating protection for head zone (aka safeZone)
  cooldown   = false, // is key in cooldown mode
  score    = 0; // current score

// game main loop
function loop()
{
  // logic
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

  // force speed
  px += xv;
  py += yv;

  // teleports
  if( px > canv.width )
    {px = 0;}

  if( px + pw < 0 )
    {px = canv.width;}

  if( py + ph < 0 )
    {py = canv.height;}

  if( py > canv.height )
    {py = 0;}

  // paint the snake itself with the tail elements
  ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
  for( var i = 0; i < trail.length; i++ )
  {
    ctx.fillStyle = trail[i].color || 'lime';
    ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x, trail[i].y, pw, ph);
  }

  trail.push({x: px, y: py, color: ctx.fillStyle});

  // limiter
  if( trail.length > tail )
  {
    trail.shift();
  }

  // eaten
  if( trail.length > tail )
  {
    trail.shift();
  }

  // self collisions
  if( trail.length >= tail && gs )
  {
    for( var i = trail.length - tailSafeZone; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
      if(
        px < (trail[i].x + pw)
        && px + pw > trail[i].x
        && py < (trail[i].y + ph)
        && py + ph > trail[i].y
      )
      {
        // got collision
        tail = 10; // cut the tail
        speed = baseSpeed; // cut the speed (flash nomore lol xD)

        for( var t = 0; t < trail.length; t++ )
        {
          // highlight lossed area
          trail[t].color = 'red';

          if( t >= trail.length - tail )
            {break;}
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // paint apples
  for( var a = 0; a < apples.length; a++ )
  {
    ctx.fillStyle = apples[a].color;
    ctx.fillRect(apples[a].x, apples[a].y, aw, ah);
  }

  // check for snake head collisions with apples
  for( var a = 0; a < apples.length; a++ )
  {
    if(
      px < (apples[a].x + pw)
      && px + pw > apples[a].x
      && py < (apples[a].y + ph)
      && py + ph > apples[a].y
    )
    {
      // got collision with apple
      apples.splice(a, 1); // remove this apple from the apples list
      tail += 10; // add tail length
      speed += .1; // add some speed
      spawnApple(); // spawn another apple(-s)
      break;
    }
  }
}

// apples spawner
function spawnApple()
{
  var
    newApple = {
      x: ~~(Math.random() * canv.width),
      y: ~~(Math.random() * canv.height),
      color: 'red'
    };

  // forbid to spawn near the edges
  if(
    (newApple.x < aw || newApple.x > canv.width - aw)
    ||
    (newApple.y < ah || newApple.y > canv.height - ah)
  )
  {
    spawnApple();
    return;
  }

  // check for collisions with tail element, so no apple will be spawned in it
  for( var i = 0; i < tail.length; i++ )
  {
    if(
      newApple.x < (trail[i].x + pw)
      && newApple.x + aw > trail[i].x
      && newApple.y < (trail[i].y + ph)
      && newApple.y + ah > trail[i].y
    )
    {
      // got collision
      spawnApple();
      return;
    }
  }

  apples.push(newApple);

  if( apples.length < 3 && ~~(Math.random() * 1000) > 700 )
  {
    // 30% chance to spawn one more apple
    spawnApple();
  }
}

// random color generator (for debugging purpose or just 4fun)
function rc()
{
  return '#' + ((~~(Math.random() * 255)).toString(16)) + ((~~(Math.random() * 255)).toString(16)) + ((~~(Math.random() * 255)).toString(16));
}

// velocity changer (controls)
function changeDirection(evt)
{
  if( !fkp && [37,38,39,40].indexOf(evt.keyCode) > -1 )
  {
    setTimeout(function() {gs = true;}, 1000);
    fkp = true;
    spawnApple();
  }

  if( cooldown )
    {return false;}

  /*
    4 directional movement.
   */
  if( evt.keyCode == 37 && !(xv > 0) ) // left arrow
    {xv = -speed; yv = 0;}

  if( evt.keyCode == 38 && !(yv > 0) ) // top arrow
    {xv = 0; yv = -speed;}

  if( evt.keyCode == 39 && !(xv < 0) ) // right arrow
    {xv = speed; yv = 0;}

  if( evt.keyCode == 40 && !(yv < 0) ) // down arrow
    {xv = 0; yv = speed;}

  cooldown = true;
  setTimeout(function() {cooldown = false;}, 100);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="mc"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, с айди всё окей. Лучше просто на эту змею забью

Comment: Возможно скрипт срабатывает до того, как `canvas` появляется в разметке

Answer (score 0):

Я узнал решение этой проблемы. Я в айди и getElementById поставил разны скобки, и я ещё скрипт поставил после канвы. Вот и всё